# HTML: How to change the separator between date and time of input type="datetime-local" by a blank space instead of a coma?

Tags: html, input, datetimepicker, separator, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the type="datetime-local" of input.

he example that I am using can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local. I've changed it a bit so I can include a placeholder (find that little code below)

Everything works fine. However, I would like to have a blank space as a separator instead of a coma but I have no clue how to do this and haven't found anything useful so far.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<input
type="text" onfocus="(this.type='datetime-local')"
placeholder="Date and Time"
name="meeting-time" step="300"
min="2019-06-07T00:00" max="2022-06-14T00:00">
```

Comment: When I run your example - and when I regenerate it here as a running SO snippet - I cannot find a comma as a separator. Can you explain exactly what type of result you would expect?

Comment: when I pick the desired date and time the format is 20/09/2019, 22:44. I would not like that coma to be there. Only one blank space, i.e., 20/09/2019 22:44. I've checked both in Chrome and Edge (it does not work on Firefox nor Safari)

Comment: That comma is based on your browser's locale setting. You would need to update that, as datetime-local is always going to be in the user's preferred date format.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. But based on @cars10m comment, I assume it is browser specific, and not something you can change. Nor should you. Users should have the same experience with that input type across sites. By removing the comma, you may make it look more like what you want, but it breaks the user's expectations they've learned from other sites.

Comment: I did try your snippet with two language settings "EN-en" ("06/12/2018 07:30 PM") and "de" ("12.06.2018 19:30"). I got a different format in each locale, but neither of them contained a comma. I tested on Windows 10 with Chrome.

Comment: One more take back! Looking in my Mac's Language and Region settings, I see that dates with times are displayed with a comma separator, so it is coming from the OS. The Mozilla documentation mentions this as well "the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system"